# Finding the roots of a cubic equation and the value of an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose a, b, and c are the roots of $$x^3-4x+1=0$$ Find the numerical value of $$\frac {a^2bc}{a^3+1}+\frac {ab^2c}{b^3+1} +\frac {abc^2}{c^3+1}$$

By using Vietas Formula, I found that:
$$a+b+c=0$$
$$ab+bc+ac=-4$$
$$abc=-1$$

It followed that 
$$a^2bc=-a$$
$$ab^2c=-b$$
$$abc^2=-c$$

I tried to simplify the expression by combining the sum into one fraction. I found, by manipulation, that $$a^3+b^3+c^3=-3.$$ Also,$ (abc)^3=-1 $and cancels with 1 in the denominator. I stopped here.

Can anyone help me in continuing? Or can anyone help me in finding a better solution than mine?

Comment: *Hint*: $\frac{a^2bc}{a^3+1} = -\frac{a}{a^3+1}$ since $abc=-1$ as you noted, and $a^3-4a+1=0\implies a^3+1 = 4a$.

Comment: So cool! I never thought of that idea--the one with $a^3-4a+1=0.$ Thank very much for your help.